# How do I add an instance variable inside of a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I would like to make this :

```
= link_to 'Click this link!", 'http://www.mydomain.com/#{@id}/manage', :target => '_blank'
```

This is getting sent as an email..and the `@id` is coming from my Notifier model..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fell for it again! I had to make those double quotes like this :

```
 = link_to 'click here.', "http://www.mydomain.com/#{@org_id}/manage", :target => '_blank'
```

Back to rails school I go

Comment: Actually the problem was that you opened with a single quote and closed with a double quote in your question.

Comment: If you always use double quotes unless you specifically need an alternative you won't get burned by this as often.